# PHP: Does Google OAuth2 refresh token need to be in a cookie to always be available?

Tags: php, google-oauth

Does the Google OAuth2 refresh token need to be stored in a "forever-lasting" cookie so that there is always a way to retrieve it?  Imagine this repeat visit scenario...

**1st user visit:**

1. Use authorization code to get a refresh token and an access token.
2. Store refresh token in a $_SESSION for later. Great!

**2nd user visit (same day or few days later):**

1. Access token expired.  We can only use the authorization code once to get an access token.
2. No problem! Use refresh token from $_SESSION to get a new access token. Great!

**3rd user visit (a month or year later):**

1. **Access token expired.**
2. **$_SESSION expired too.**
3. Oh no! We need the refresh token... **How do I get the refresh token now?**

If $_SESSION expires too with the access token, how do we find it? Does the refresh token have to be stored in a cookie?

Thought about storing the refresh token inside a MySQL database BUT since the user is NOT logged in to begin with, there is no way to use their ID in the database and link it to the refresh token through a query.

So, is the cookie the only answer here?  Maybe I'm missing something...I was trying to NOT use cookies but I guess I have no choice?

Comment: `$_SESSION` is basically using a cookie to set it's session ID in the client, therefore you're already using cookies ;)

Comment: Thanks. I suppose I just need to make it last forever since Google refresh token lasts 15 years?

Comment: It's really depending on what you want. If you want your users to have to authenticate only once for your application, there is no other choice than to store something for a long time.

Comment: OK! Upon logout of the website I was using session_destroy() but then all the data is lost and the user is effectively locked out forever unless I revoke the token.